# 1D score from 3-class LDA

Tags: discriminant-analysis

I am using 3-class linear discriminant analysis on a data set. The 3 class labels correspond to a single value, with high, mid and low values (labels -1, 0, and 1). 
The 3-class LDA works much better than 2-class when classifying against a test set.

But I need to transform the 3 class scores into a single score. I'm having trouble with the middle set. What I tried is:

```
new_score = (label==-1)*(1-scores(1)) + (label==1)*(scores(3)) + (label==0)*(scores(3)-scores(1))/3+0.5)
```

Which does a reasonable job. But, is there a better way to transform the 3-score set into a single score?

Comment: How do you compute the score?

Comment: Matlab LDA. 
   [c_label, c_score, c_cost] = predict(lda_object, data_matrix)